# Inserting self-referential records in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Given the following table in PostgreSQL, how do I insert a record which refers to itself?

```
CREATE TABLE refers (
    id        SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_id INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES refers(id)
);
```

The examples I'm finding on the Web have been allowed the parent_id to be NULL and then use a trigger to update it.  I'd rather update in one shot, if possible.

Comment: By one shot, you mean 1 query or using transaction?

Comment: @Pentium10: one query. Something like: "INSERT INTO refers (name, parent_id) VALUES ('foo', :id)".  That being said, I'll still happily take the cleanest recommendation people have :)

Comment: I don't think that this is possible in 1 query. I've some pragmas to disable foreign key checks, that can help for the not null issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can select last_value from the sequence, that is automatically created when you use type serial:

```
create table test (
  id serial primary key,
  parent integer not null,
  foreign key (parent) references test(id)
);

insert into test values(default, (select last_value from test_id_seq));
insert into test values(default, (select last_value from test_id_seq));
insert into test values(default, (select last_value from test_id_seq));

select * from test;
 id | parent
----+--------
  1 |      1
  2 |      2
  3 |      3
(3 rows)
```

And the following even simpler seems to work as well:

```
insert into test values(default, lastval());
```

Though I don't know how this would work when using multiple sequences... I looked it up; lastval() returns the last value returned or set with the last nextval or setval call to any sequence, so the following would get you in trouble:

```
create table test (
  id serial primary key,
  foo serial not null,
  parent integer not null,
  foreign key (parent) references test(id)
);

select setval('test_foo_seq', 100);

insert into test values(default, default, lastval());
ERROR:  insert or update on table "test" violates foreign key constraint "test_parent_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (parent)=(101) is not present in table "test".
```

However the following would be okay:

```
insert into test values(default, default, currval('test_id_seq'));

select * from test;
 id | foo | parent
----+-----+--------
  2 | 102 |      2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I used the more explicit "test_id_seq" just to be safe. Thanks!

Comment: It's old, I know, but it is guaranteed that parameters of values(...) are evaluated from left to right? If not, I guess it would be possible that lastval()/select last_value ... is still returning the previous value.

Comment: @MarcinKrupowicz To be honest, I am not sure about that. However, all the tests that I performed were working without a hitch for me.

Answer (score 3):

The main question is - why would you want to insert record which relates to itself?

Schema looks like standard adjacency list - one of methods to implement trees in relational database.

The thing is that in most cases you simply have parent_id **NULL** for top-level element. This is actually much simpler to handle.

Comment: This is a valid design and more natural for some than adjacency lists, especially with recursive queries.

Comment: Having a value forces you to have more complete/valid data. NULLs are fine however in practise this leads to data quality or being unsure of the data.

Comment: "not null" constraint on parent_id column can be usable sometimes